# Github for Windows 7: Missing libeay32.dll

Tags: windows-7, git

I'm new to using `git` and github.com. Via an ubuntu machine, I've created a repository on github.com, and I've committed to this already. Now, I'd like to use the code on my Windows 7 machine as well. Following the instructions, I've installed `github for windows 1.3.2.0` from https://windows.github.com/. The program itself starts just fine, I can log in as a github user, and I can create local repositories. On github.com, there's an ssh key listed with the name of my windows machine.

However, I cannot publish local changes to github.com, and also, I cannot clone existing (online) repositories which are listed within github for windows.

When I try to start the clone process, I get an error message of git-remot-https.exe: "The programm cannot be started since LIBEAY32.dll is missing. Reinstall the programm to solve this problem" (translated into English by me).

Then, the github for windows program propts "Failed to clone the repository 'RepoName' Please check your internet connection"

When I try to publish a local repo, I get a similar error message and "error Failed to Publish this branch."

When I try to clone the remote repo via a shell, e.g. `git clone https://github.com/MyUserName/SomeRepo.git`, it does not do anything. The message "Cloning into 'RepoName'" appears, no error message, but also no changes in the folder. In particular, `git status` does not recognize the folder as a git repo.

I've posted the log below, but I don't see anything related in there. The only instance of `libeay32.dll` I can find is hiding in a package-subfolder of `R`. I've installed the .NET frameworks 4 and 4.5, as advised by the github installer.

Did I forget to install something to make github for windows work?

GitHubLog.txt:

> 2014-04-25 18:59:45.4532|WARN|thread:1|POCOObservableForProperty|GitHub.Models.ChangeLog is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
>   2014-04-25 18:43:56.3362|WARN|thread:1|LogHost|SuppressChangeNotifications was called (perhaps via AddRange), yet you do not
>   2014-04-25 18:43:56.3362|WARN|thread:1|LogHost|have a subscription to ShouldReset. This probably isn't what you want, as ItemsAdded
>   2014-04-25 18:43:56.3362|WARN|thread:1|LogHost|and friends will appear to 'miss' items
>   2014-04-25 18:43:57.2483|WARN|thread:1|POCOObservableForProperty|GitHub.Views.TwoFactorView is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
>   2014-04-25 18:43:57.2783|WARN|thread:1|POCOObservableForProperty|GitHub.Views.UndoFlashView is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
>   2014-04-25 18:43:57.3093|WARN|thread:1|POCOObservableForProperty|GitHub.Views.ShellView is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
>   2014-04-25 18:43:57.6133|WARN|thread:1|POCOObservableForProperty|GitHub.Views.Controls.OptionsMenu is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
>   2014-04-25 18:43:58.1933|WARN|thread:1|LogHost|SuppressChangeNotifications was called (perhaps via AddRange), yet you do not
>   2014-04-25 18:43:58.1933|WARN|thread:1|LogHost|have a subscription to ShouldReset. This probably isn't what you want, as ItemsAdded
>   2014-04-25 18:43:58.1933|WARN|thread:1|LogHost|and friends will appear to 'miss' items
>   2014-04-25 18:52:58.4279|WARN|thread:1|POCOObservableForProperty|GitHub.Views.Controls.PushToHostButton is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
>   2014-04-25 18:52:58.5349|WARN|thread:1|POCOObservableForProperty|GitHub.Views.Controls.RepositoryOptionsMenu is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
>   2014-04-25 18:52:58.5619|WARN|thread:1|POCOObservableForProperty|GitHub.Views.RepositoryView is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
>   2014-04-25 18:52:59.0250|WARN|thread:1|POCOObservableForProperty|GitHub.Views.FileDiffView is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
>   2014-04-25 18:59:45.3592|WARN|thread:1|POCOObservableForProperty|GitHub.Views.Controls.LicenseBrowser is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!
>   2014-04-25 18:59:45.3892|WARN|thread:1|POCOObservableForProperty|GitHub.Views.AboutView is a POCO type and won't send change notifications, WhenAny will only return a single value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find `libeay32.dll` as part of the [Windows version of OpenSSL](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Comment: This fixed the issues from OP.